# Memcached raising a strange Key Error

Tags: python-2.7, caching, memcached

Disclaimer: I'm very new to memcached, so this might (is probably) a stupid mistake on my part.For my internship, I'm using pymemcache 1.2.9.  I inherited a project from a previous intern who I can't contact easily and no one I'm working with has any knowledge of this project.

The keys are added to a locally hosted cache in a fairly straightforward way - the key is a string and the data is a string that comes from a google API (geopy) we're using.  However, when I try to see if the key exists in the cache:

```
    if not cache.get(key):
         #python stuff
         cache.add(key, values)
```

This works about half of the time and the rest of the time I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
   File "card_visualization.py", line 69, in fetcher_thread
if not cache.get(key):
   File "/home/arnold/.virtualenvs/datavis/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymemcache/client.py", line 458, in get
return self._fetch_cmd(b'get', [key], False).get(key, None)
  File "/home/arnold/.virtualenvs/datavis/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymemcache/client.py", line 723, in _fetch_cmd
key = checked_keys[key]
 KeyError: 'my_acceptable_key'
```

What's confusing is that different keys cause this error and it happens with absolutely no regularity.

Comment: EDIT: fixed this problem. I was running multithreading in python - one thread would go and put something in the cache and another thread would check if that thing is in the cache.  Moral of the story: don't using multithreading and memcached unless you're sure how both of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, it seems that when using multiprocessing you sometimes just get cache misses on existing keys.

Pymemcache offers a Retrying client https://pymemcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#using-the-built-in-retrying-mechanism

Or you can literally just write a try-except that retries getting a key 10 times since the odds of a miss are very low and when it does happen doing the same request over again usually just works and the delay is very small.